# Java / Node.js - Procedure call

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, inversion-of-control

I have an own written Java container which uses *Inversion of Control (IoC)*, thus the container expects an implementation of a certain interface.

Example of the interface:

```
public interface OnWrite {
    void onWrite(Context context);
}
```

Now, I'd like the user to provide the **implementation not in Java but in JavaScript**, hence the user writes JavaScript code.

Example of the user provided JavaScript implementation:

```
function onWrite(context) {
    // Do something
}
```

The JavaScript has to be executed by Node.js.
The only one solution I can imagine is, that the *context* objects on both sides are proxy objects, which comunicate through sockets.

Do you have any other ideas? I appreciete any suggestions.